# "In prison" or "Imprisonment"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I was wondering which sentence below sounds more idiomatic?

> 1- He was condemned to 20 years **in prison** and he paid the cost for his actions. 
> 2- He was condemned to 20 years **imprisonment** and he paid the cost for his actions.

I am asking this question, because there is the collocation: "life imprisonment", but the original sentence was written with "in prison" (#1)! So that was why I became confused and decided to bring the question up here.
Please kindly explain that to me.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie. I have edited the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `condemned` should be reserved for a more abstract usage here and `sentence` should be used instead since it refers to a specific sentencing (of 20 years).

> Unequivocally condemned by society, he was sentenced to the nation's most notorious prison where he paid the price of his actions with twenty years of his life.

That said, I'd opt for the second choice because we can safely assume it would be inside a prison, whereas imprisonment has a more interesting connotation in this usage, in my opinion.

Comment: Right,sentenced is used for criminals in court cases.

Comment: Thank you very much @bsod. Just may I invite you to a chat-room to ask about some other examples to be able to differentiate between "condemn" and "sentence"?

Comment: @A-friend sure, if you wish.